# How do you turn a variable into a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, object, variables

I have been searching around and in most forums the reply to this question is more or less that it's unnecessary to convert a variable into string. However given the following scenario how could I go about solving the problem?

I have an object `categories` as follows:

```
const categories = {
  1: ctgOne,
  2: ctgTwo,
  3: ctgThree,
  4: ctgFour,
};
```

These categories correspond to objects which contain some arbitrary data:

```
const ctgOne = {
  test1: ["blah", "blah", "blah"],
  test2: ["blah", "blah", "blah"],
};
const ctgTwo = {
  test1: ["blah", "blah", "blah"],
  test2: ["blah", "blah", "blah"],
  test3: ["blah", "blah", "blah"],
};
const ctgThree = {
  test1: ["blah", "blah", "blah"],
  test3: ["blah", "blah", "blah"],
};
const ctgFour = {
  test2: ["blah", "blah", "blah"],
  test3: ["blah", "blah", "blah"],
};
```

I have another object `categoryList` containing some numbers associated to each category in arrays:

```
const categoryList = {
  ctgOne: [1, 3, 5, 8, 13],
  ctgTwo: [23, 4, 78],
  ctgThree: [12, 33, 54, 8, 13, 12, 45],
  ctgFour: [1, 35, 5, 2],
};
```

When I run the following script, I get an error for the second `console.log(count);` for obvious reasons because in `count = categoryList[categoryName].length;` "categoryName" is required to be a string. However, if I convert the categories in my `categories` object to strings, `console.log(keys);` gives me the length of the string instead of the number of keys in the object.

```
let categoryNumber = 1;
let categoryName = categories[categoryNumber];

let keys = Object.keys(categoryName).length;

console.log(keys);

count = categoryList[categoryName].length;

console.log(count);
```

What would be the best approach to solve this dilemma? I want to count the number of keys in the object as well as the numbers in the `categoryList`.

Comment: do you need `1`, `2`, ... as category keys? why not take `ctgOne`, etc as keys?

Comment: Yes, because each category is associated to the number.

Comment: do you need this number?

Comment: Yes, because each corresponding number is like the number value of the category. 1 is ctgOne, 2 is ctgTwo etc. You can compare it with a lookup value.

Comment: What is the second set of objects with the "blah" content  about?

Comment: please add a use case for all.

Comment: btw, why not use `1`, `2`, etc as keys for `categoryList`? it is the same to take numbers instead of nonmeaningful names.

Comment: That is basically a dictionary containing specified information about the category. So, test1, test2... would be some sub-descriptions of the category and blah blah is just the content.

Comment: @NinaScholz That still does not resolve the issue because categoryName is till not a string.

Comment: still the question, why `1` instead of `ctgOne` as key? what is the deeper meaning of `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get variable names as strings. At best, you'll get to do it the other way round, but really you should never care about variable names as data. You can (and should) inline those 4 `const` variables in your `categories` object.

To get the respective value from the other object, use the *same keys* in both `categories` and `categoryList`. That is, either

```
const categories = {
  ctgOne: { test1: …, test2: …},
  ctgTwo: { test1: …, test2: …, test3: …},
  ctgThree: { test1: …, test3: …},
  ctgFour: { test2: …, test3: …},
};
const categoryList = {
  ctgOne: [1, 3, 5, 8, 13],
  ctgTwo: [23, 4, 78],
  ctgThree: [12, 33, 54, 8, 13, 12, 45],
  ctgFour: [1, 35, 5, 2],
};
```

or

```
const categories = {
  1: { test1: …, test2: …},
  2: { test1: …, test2: …, test3: …},
  3: { test1: …, test3: …},
  4: { test2: …, test3: …},
};
const categoryList = {
  1: [1, 3, 5, 8, 13],
  2: [23, 4, 78],
  3: [12, 33, 54, 8, 13, 12, 45],
  4: [1, 35, 5, 2],
};
```

but not a mix of them. If you really need both of them, you won't get away without a separate mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

In your object, why dont you store the object name, which is a string.

In your categoryList, use the name, instead of the objects, as keys.

For example,

```
const ctgOne = {
    name: "Category 1",
    test1: ...,
    test2: ...
}
const ctgTwo = {
    name: "Category 2",
    test1: ...,
    test2: ...
}

const categoryList = {
    "Category 1": [1, 3, 5, 8, 13],
    "Category 2": [23, 4, 78],
}
```

Then you can do

```
let categoryNumber = 1;
let category = categories[category];
let categoryName = category.name;

let keys = Object.keys(category).length;

console.log(keys);

count = categoryList[categoryName].length;

console.log(count);
```

Comment: I didn't quite get what you mean!?

Comment: Edited answer with example.